# Stripping <ins> and <del> tags from <script> tags

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I have some code that is generating a diff between two documents, inserting `<ins>` and `<del>` tags haphazardly. For the most part it's doing a great job, but every now and then it inserts tags in script, style and the title tags.

Any ideas on how to *remove* the `<del>` tags (including the text between them), remove the `<ins>` tags (but retaining the text within them as part of the original string), however only within those three tags? (title, script and style).

Comment: strip tags http://php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php maybe?

Comment: A note: use backticks or the editor's "code" button when you're including HTML tags within the text of your post. Otherwise, people won't be able to see them.

Comment: @JuanFernandoz Not sure the best way to use that given my situation. I wouldn't want to remove all tags between the script tags. John Thanks for that. I always forget :)

Comment: @onassar with strip tags you can remove all tags but preserve the tags that you want. For example:  $a = (strip_tags($content, '<p><a><tbody><table><header><meta><td>
  <tr>')); in that example you only preserve the marked tags between parentheses.

Comment: I would still need to find a regular expression to match it.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regex to do this; it sounds like you have to deal with many, many lines.  DOMDocument is great.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($your_html_string);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//script|//title|//style') as $node) {
    foreach ($node->getElementsByTagName('del') as $delNode) {
        $node->removeChild($delNode);
    }
    foreach ($node->getElementsByTagName('ins') as $insNode) {
       $node->replaceChild($dom->createTextNode($insNode->nodeValue), $insNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about that, but if I then use saveHTML to output it, it generates different markup (eg. adds a doctype, does some optimizations, etc.)

Comment: @onassar you can get around that by using `saveXML` with a specific node

Comment: How do I then re-render the markup? I would have to write it to a file somehow.

Comment: @onassar how were you planning to rerender it with the regex?

Comment: I was hoping to use `preg_replace` on the original string.

Comment: @onassar You're using `DOMDocument` on the whole string already.  `$str = (string)$dom->saveXML($xpath->query('//body/OUTERMOST_ELEMENT')->item(0))`

Comment: That dom call will replace only the specific xpath subject with the replace contents?

Comment: @onassar the xpath is practically the entire document, but it's just done that way to avoid DOMDocument "helpfully" adding doctype, xml declaration, etc.

Comment: I'll give that a go now. One sec.

Comment: @onassar that's just a placeholder; you probably know what the outermost element is.  In case you don't, just wrap the entire string in `<p>...</p>` and use the xpath `//body/p`

Comment: I'm not following. I load the document into the dom object, make the mods I have, but now how do I get this changed markup back to the var?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24488/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-onassar)

Answer (score 1):

Untested, this may or may not work:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(<script.*?>.*?)<del>.*?</del>(.*?</script>)/im', '$1$2', $str);
```

It attempts to look within the <script> ... </script> block of the string, and replace any instances of <del>...</del> with empty string.

Comment: The script tags could have attributes attached to them, as well as the style tags.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the solution to take account of script attributes. Also to make it case-insensitive and multi-line. Poster should extend to also replace the <ins> tags.

Comment: I'm trying this now, but it doesn't seem to catch all cases (eg. new lines between some of the del tags, etc.)

Comment: "may or may not work" describes parsing HTML with regex in general quite accurate.

Answer (score 0):

The following ended up working quite well for me:

```
$tags = array('script', 'title', 'style');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $str = preg_replace_callback(
        '/(<' . ($tag) . '\b[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/' . ($tag) . '>)/is',
        function($match) {
            $replaced = preg_replace(
                array(
                    '/__Delete-Start__.+__Delete-End__/Uis',
                    '/__Insert-Start__(.+)__Insert-End__/Uis'
                ),
                array(
                    '',
                    '$1'
                ),
                $match[2]
            );
            return ($match[1]) . ($replaced) . ($match[3]);
        },
        $str
    );
}
```

While the following didn't end up being my solution, it did get me far and could be useful to others:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//script|//title|//style') as $node) {
    foreach ($node->getElementsByTagName('del') as $delNode) {
        $node->removeChild($delNode);
    }
    foreach ($node->getElementsByTagName('ins') as $insNode) {
        $node->replaceChild($dom->createTextNode($insNode->nodeValue), $insNode);
    }
}
$str = (string) $dom->saveXML($dom, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);//$xpath->query('//p')->item(0));
```

Hope this helps someone else.